# Best way to display data in rows and coloumn format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

i am doing an app for iPhone which has to display the details of students of school  i.e. their name,class name,marks in different subjects.I have to display the same in rows and columns format
Can anybody suggest me the best way to implement a 7 column table

Comment: You can customize UITableView. That will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If You only want display the information then in Custom UITableViewCell put 7 UILabels Horizontally depends on your UI.If you also want some action on them then  put UIButtons in place of UILabel.

Comment: i will check out custom uitableviewcell.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1265678:hiii,check this [link](http://riaiphone.blogspot.in/2012/02/multiple-columns-in-uitableview.html).it will really help you to solve your problem.